# Alibaba android app causes crash when you try to open an URL

Tags: android, url, webview, crash, external

When you try to open a link, from example from whatsapp, the app (in this case whatsapp) crashes. This only happens if you have alibaba app installed in your device.
Reproduction path:

1. install alibaba app (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alibaba.intl.android.apps.poseidon&hl=en)
2. try to open url
3. app crashes (or it can't find any
   other activities to open the link, even not the chrome browser.)

   The crash what we see in our app is:

   Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://www.nu.nl cmp=com.alibaba.intl.android.apps.poseidon/com.alibaba.android.intl.weex.activity.WeexPageActivity VirtualScreenParam=Params{mDisplayId=-1, null, mFlags=0x00000000)} } from ProcessRecord{7307f55 18243:.../u0a226} (pid=18243, uid=10226) not exported from uid 10207

Comment: Alibaba Manifest:
https://github.com/alibaba/weex/blob/4abcd6cf0070c6301ed64d6bbcdef727365f347e/android/playground/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L49

Comment: Pretty sure the same issue happens with their Aliexpress app as well. Once I cleared defaults for it, my in app browser requests started working again.

Comment: i dont really understand why this is crashing our app and i need to fix it. lol. jesus christ

Answer (score 8):

From what I infer, this is a bug corresponding to the alibaba app. Firstly it is associated with deep linking feature which allows Apps to open URI indigenous to them. For example : quora app or reddit app. This would open inside the Quora instead of Chrome to enhance the experience.

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <data
     android:host="reddit.com"
     android:pathPrefix="/r"
     android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>
```

Something like this. I suspect that the alibaba app would have routed all the hosts towards their app. They would have liberally used the wildcards which would have made their app to be opened from literally any url. Also the crash is due to denial of permission. This happens when you try to open a non-exported activity from context outside of the app.

PS: In short words, this is solely an issue with alibaba B2B app. This can only be fixed from their side. Try clearing defaults and routing all urls back to chrome as android asks your choice to select the default application for any uri.

Comment: Because their activity is not exported, the OS throws an exception but that cause other apps to crash. I think Android shouldn't be that depended on only one app, in this case Alibaba.

Comment: You see the host attribute there ? What if I replace it with a wildcard ? But Android won't allow it to route there. Simple solution is to open Applications menu in Settings and press the gear icon in top right of action bar. In the new settings screen, click opening links and change open links in this app by default to Ask Everytime. This would fix the issue.

Comment: That might help, but you can't ask your users to do this in their apps?! All other apps crash if you try to open a link. IMHO, Android has to fix this.

Comment: https://github.com/alibaba/weex/blob/4abcd6cf0070c6301ed64d6bbcdef727365f347e/android/playground/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L49

Comment: https://github.com/alibaba/weex/issues/2139 Check this issue. They will fix it soon.

Comment: Still, I believe, that Android should come with a good solution for this issue. You can't let the app crash just because one App couldn't handle the intent (because it was not exported)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132704/discussion-between-ungoogleable-and-ashik-vetrivelu).

Comment: this is f**king ridiculous.

Comment: Same problem here, a few crashes on my app thanks to this guys. There should be a way to flag it so Google removes their app from the Store.